# HTML table headers with different widths than cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm trying to make an HTML table where the `<th>`'s have a different width than the `<td>`'s, yet still be aligned. I'm wondering if that's possible to do with CSS/JavaScript. Also, I'm using the DataTables jQuery plugin to create my HTML since I need fixed headers/first column.

Here's how the table currently looks: *(see first image in the album)*

I want to squish the td's together, but the table headers are too wide. If I just squish the td's together without doing anything to the th's, then the table loses alignment. (I know it looks horrible with the border, it just helps show the misalignment)

I changed the width by altering the width calculated by the DataTables/FixedColumns plugin. Trying to change the width of the headers doesn't give me the effect that I want.

*(see second image in the album)*

Finally, this is an example of pretty much what I'm looking for. See how the table headers overlap with each other?

*(see final image in the album)*

I was wondering if this is possible to do with CSS/JavaScript? Sorry for not posting links to the individual images, I'm new to the site and I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links. Thanks a lot, everyone!

**Image album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOHFt.jpg**

Comment: Do you have any code to start with? If yes, please include it in your question and, better yet, create a http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search and I found this: https://web.archive.org/web/20131227124521/http://s-church.net/Blog/Entry/464

Looks like exactly what you want:

[image]

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

HTML code -

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=3>Values (Type A)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=3>Values (Type B)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS code -

```
th {
    background-color: #4072B4;
}
td {
    background-color: #608DC9
}
```

---

1. http://jsfiddle.net/CLvD2/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#Attributes